# Command Prompt: Execute Commands from Any Text File (Not Having ".bat" or ".cmd" Extensions)

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, file-extension

I can't find any way to do, for example, the following:

`cmd.exe /C "script.txt"`

In other words, I need Command Prompt to (try) to execute file with any extension (not necessarily `.bat` or `.cmd`) if it contains valid batch script code. I'm looking for behavior similar to Unix shells:

`./script.txt`

While on Unix the *shebang* (`#!/bin/sh`) is responsible for understanding that the file is actually a script, it seems like on Windows `.bat` or `.cmd` extensions play the same role, indicating a batch script file for Command Prompt.

Is it possible to avoid that and force Command Prompt to interpret a file with any name?

**NOTE:** Please, no answers like:

> Give your file `.bat` or `.cmd` extension.

That's not what the question is about.

Comment: Change your extension to `.bat` or `.cmd` ;) (could not resist...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818031/use-shebang-hashbang-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm aware about this method and I've tried it before posting here. The main point where it fails is that one simply cannot execute `cmd.exe /C ""%1" %*"` as `%1` will have `.foo` extension and not `.bat` or `.cmd`. As a result, this method does not work either...

Comment: This is a hacking question, probably better suited to Superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you first need an "installation"  script :

```
   @echo off

    rem :: A files with .TEST extension will be able to execute batch code but is not perfect as the %0 argument is lost

    rem :: "installing" a caller.
    if not exist "c:\caller.bat" (
       echo @echo off
       echo copy "%%~nx1"  "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat" /Y ^>nul
       echo "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat"  %%*
    ) > c:\caller.bat

    rem :: associating file extension
    assoc .test=batps
    ftype batps=c:\caller "%%1" %*
```

then try a simple `.test`  file:

```
@echo off
for /l (1;1;10) do (
  echo testing .TEST extension
)
```

In fact `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` both have immediate effect so you can start a `.test` file right after "installation". With direct editing of the registry eventually you can get more control -> [How to create file extension that behaves as .cmd/.bat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581987/how-to-create-file-extension-that-behaves-as-cmd-bat)  . Check also drop handlers -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I thought about making a renamed temporary copy as well. Indeed that should work. However, that feels too hackish, but as far as I can see, it's probably the only feasible solution. That Windows...

Comment: I've tried a lot of things (mainly in the registries) but I think it's forbidden .This is the only way I've found.

Comment: Well, of course it's hackish - you're trying to do a hackish thing!

Comment: ... as an optimization, you could use a link rather than an actual copy.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the complexity of the NON-Batch file. If the NON-Batch file does not use these facilities:

- Access to Batch file parameters via %1 %2 ... and execution of SHIFT command.
- Execution of GOTO command.
- Execution of CALL :NAME command (internal subroutine).
- Execution of SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL commands.

then you may execute *any* file as a "Batch file" via this trick:

```
cmd < anyFile.ext
```

Further details at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-with-out-using-bat-extention/13337597#13337597)

Comment: The restrictions are quite harsh to be honest. Anyway, nice to know that this could be an option in some cases. Thanks.