# Call file with custom extension in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using a second batch file in my main one to save/load variables, like this:

```
if not exist "KeemyDataPersistence.bat" (
echo @ECHO OFF > KeemyDataPersistence.bat
echo SET GENDER=F >> KeemyDataPersistence.bat
echo SET BGCOLOR=0 >> KeemyDataPersistence.bat
echo SET FGCOLOR=2 >> KeemyDataPersistence.bat
)
call KeemyDataPersistence.bat
```

It's working fine, but I'd like to save that second file (`KeemyDataPersistence.bat`) with another extension (`.keemy`), so `KeemyDataPersistence.keemy`. It saves fine just by replacing .bat by .keemy in the whole code, but when using `call KeemyDataPersistence.keemy`, it runs the windows default window to choose the program the user wants to open it with.

How would I be able to make it call the file as a batch file?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162474/command-prompt-execute-commands-from-any-text-file-not-having-bat-or-cmd)

Answer (score 2):

Try first to run this script  once with admin permissions (and .bat extension):

```
   @echo off

    rem :: A files with .keemy extension will be able to execute batch code but is not perfect as the %0 argument is lost

    rem :: "installing" a caller.
    if not exist "c:\caller.bat" (
       echo @echo off
       echo copy "%%~nx1"  "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat" /Y ^>nul
       echo "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat"  %%*
    ) > c:\caller.bat

    rem :: associating file extension
    assoc .keemy=batps
    ftype batps=c:\caller "%%1" %*
```