# Simple ftype command not working

Tags: batch-file, command

I am trying to get ftype create a new filetype but it is not working :(. Here is my command: `ftype testing="cmd.exe" "%1"` but it says `File type 'testing' not found or no open command associated with it.`

I don't know why it is not working, I also followed the documentation mentioned in MSDN.

Comment: do you have a corresponding `assoc`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I do have a `assoc` before ftype @Stephan ;)

Comment: You must be running as administrator !!! It works in Windows 11 .

Answer (score 3):

Those commands seems not working in Vista or superior.

You don't need that anymore. Simply adjust your REGISTRY using REG.EXE command to make associations:

```
REM COMMENT
REM THIS IS AN EXAMPLE. CREATE ABOVE BATCH FILE AND EXECUTE IT.
REM You will be able to open Python files 

reg.exe add "%key%\.py" /f /t REG_SZ /d "Python.File" >NUL 2>NUL

reg.exe add "%key%\Python.File" /f /t REG_SZ /d "Python File" >NUL 2>NUL

reg.exe add "%key%\Python.File\DefaultIcon" /f /t REG_SZ /d "%pyhome%DLLs\py.ico" >NUL 2>NUL

reg.exe add "%key%\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command" /f /t REG_SZ /d "\"%pyhome%pythonw.exe\" \"%pyhome%Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw\" -e \"%%1\"" >NUL 2>NUL

reg.exe add "%key%\Python.File\shell\open\command" /f /t REG_SZ /d "\"%pyhome%pywin.bat\" \"%%1\" %%*" >NUL 2>NUL

reg.exe add "%key%\Python.File\shellex\DropHandler" /f /t REG_SZ /d "{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}" >NUL 2>NUL
```

Comment: Sorry add the first line SET  key=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

Comment: Thanks for the example... I will keep searching for a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like:

```
assoc .test=testfile
ftype testfile="cmd.exe" "%1" %*
```

though it will be not possible to create a file extension that acts like `.bat` file - because of security reasons windows will not allow this.[Here's an workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23162772/388389).

Comment: Thanks! But I thought that I need to create the file type before associating it :P

Comment: P.S the association with cmd.exe was just a silly example.